# How to remove lots of tasks in Google Tasks?

Tags: google-tasks

I accidentally pasted my clipboard into Google Tasks, and I had the content of a 40 page report in it. Google Tasks created around 1000 new tasks for each new line in the report. How can I remove them other than one by one?

Comment: are they in a single list? You can delete the whole list then.

Comment: @Bibhas, I have other stuff on the list too that is important

Answer (score 3):

Holding down the delete button for 10 minutes solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use http://code.google.com/p/google-tasks-porter/ to export (to HTML?) and a text editor to mass-edit, then import back to Google Tasks.